# Retrieving full text using twarc2

Tags: python, twitter, twarc2

I am retrieving tweets using `twarc2` with search terms in the following way:

```
twarc2 search --archive --start-time "2015-01-01" --end-time "2018-12-31" --limit 25000 "faith OR #faith" results.jsonl
```

But the resultant tweets are truncated after a certain length. E.g. `RT @AndrewYNg: We cannot abdicate responsibility when two children, ages 7 and 8, die in US custody. The US once said: "Give me your tired,…` although the [tweet](https://twitter.com/FLC_Campaign/status/1079527550836264960) is a bit longer. I read the [twarc2 documentation](https://twarc-project.readthedocs.io/en/latest/twarc2_en_us/) but can't find any `"extended"` `tweet_mode` option for retrieving the `full_text`. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the retrieved tweets truncated?  The example you provided is a retweet (includes "RT").  RT are truncated but their original tweet is full text.

You can exclude retweets in twarc2.  Try adding the below to your command:

```
-is:retweet
```

Hope that helps.